# jQuery ui chat plugin - how to guide (needed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, chat

i've (kind of) implemented a jQuery ui chat plugin that i found online https://github.com/dexterpu/jquery.ui.chatbox

i have a button on my webpage that toggles the chat box, a user can enter some text, hit enter and that text will be displayed in **their** chat box along with their username.

that's all well and good, but it's no fun really chatting to yourself. how would i go about passing data entered into the text box between two users - i'd like a user to select another user from a listbox (of logged in users), click the chat button, and the two users would be (*dragged*) in(to) the same chat box. or how would i let all chat data be globally visible to all logged in users (every logged in user sees all messages that all other users enter in their own chat box)?

some pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at SignalR?

Scott Hanselman's group is working on it.

> SignalR is an asynchronous signaling library for ASP.NET that our team
>   is working on to help build real-time multi-user web application.

Link to Scott's Blog post with code examples:
[Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

You can pull it down with [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) or here is the github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR